# Unable to compile with includegraphics using jmlr.cls

Tags: includegraphics, compilation-error

I am compiling a tex document using the jmlr.cls document class. It compiles okay without a figure but does not compile when I add a figure "circle.jpg" using the \includegraphics command. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

The error is as below.

```
Runaway argument?
circle.jpg \edef \Gin@ext {\Gin@sepdefault \filename@ext }\ifx \Gin@ext \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@tempa.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ./test.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

My code is as below:

```
\documentclass[pmlr]{jmlr}
%
\usepackage[load-configurations=version-1]{siunitx} % newer version
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{circle.jpg}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There were some adjustments to filename handling in the latest latex release, to support spaces and non ascii characters in filenames. It's clashing with the class presently so for now you can undo the support for additional characters in filenames, then if I use `example-image` which is a standard test file, as I don't have circle.jpg, it works for me,

```
\documentclass[pmlr]{jmlr}
%
\makeatletter
\def\set@curr@file#1{\def\@curr@file{#1}} %temp workaround for 2019 latex release
\makeatother
\usepackage[load-configurations=version-1]{siunitx} % newer version
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image.jpg}
\end{figure}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked!

Comment: +1: "There were some adjustments to filename handling in the latest latex release" `-->` that's good news! Can you point me to a related release note or similar?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/